# Can attribute certificates be used with TLS / HTTPS?

Tags: tls, certificates, x.509

Can attribute certificates (also known as authorization certificates) be used with HTTPS?  For instance, can a HTTPS server supply an [attribute certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization_certificate) in addition to its ordinary SSL certificate?  If yes, what will browsers do when they see it?  Do they ignore it?  Do they validate it (check that's signed by a trusted CA)?

For instance, I found [RFC 5878](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5878), which describes a TLS extension for supporting attribute certificates, but I can't tell whether it is supported by browsers.

Answer (score 2):

RFC 5878 is experimental, and therefore not required to be compliance with TLS proper. As far as I can tell, based on cursory searches, OpenSSL has headers related to 5878 (e.g. TLSEXT_TYPE_client_authz, TLSEXT_TYPE_server_authz), but does not appear to be used in either Chrome or Firefox's source code. It's non-trivial to tell if other browsers support it (e.g. Opera, Safari, Internet Explorer) without actually testing it, which I do not have the time to do at the moment. Both Chrome and Firefox *could* easily support it through their related extension APIs, or could even easily be patched to support the extension if you wanted to use that internally for an organization. Finally, I suspect that if there was support for it, a cursory Google search would confirm it, but the lack of any documentation speaks volumes.